# SQL get max value with date smaller date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this:

```
| colA | date | num |
|  x   | 1.7. |  2  |
|  x   | 3.7. |  1  |
|  x   | 4.7. |  3  |
|  z   | 1.8. |  0  |              (edit)
|  z   | 2.8. |  1  |
|  z   | 5.8. |  2  |
```

And I want a result like this:

```
| colA | date | maxNum |
|  x   | 1.7. |  null  |
|  x   | 3.7. |  2     |
|  x   | 4.7. |  2     |
|  z   | 1.8. |  null  |              (edit)
|  z   | 2.8. |  0     |
|  z   | 5.8. |  1     |
```

So I want to have the max(num) for every row where the date is smaller the date grouped by colA.
Is this somehow possible with a simple query? It would be part of a bigger query needed for some calculations on big databases.

Edit: maxNum should be null if there is no value before a date in the group

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just don't get the logic.  What does "date smaller the date group by `colA` mean?

Comment: I don't see any mention of `null` in your problem description. How do those appear in the output in the `maxNum` column? And, why isn't that explanation included in your post?

Answer (score 3):

Use `MAX..KEEP` syntax.

```
select cola, 
       adate, 
       max(num) keep ( dense_rank first order by adate ) over (partition by cola ) maxnum,
       case when adate = min(adate) over ( partition by cola ) 
            then null 
            else max(num) keep ( dense_rank first order by adate ) over (partition by cola ) end maxnum_op
from   input;
```

> ```
> +------+-------+--------+-----------+
> | COLA | ADATE | MAXNUM | MAXNUM_OP |
> +------+-------+--------+-----------+
> | x    |   1.7 |      2 |           |
> | x    |   3.7 |      2 |         2 |
> | x    |   4.7 |      2 |         2 |
> | z    |   2.8 |      1 |           |
> | z    |   5.8 |      1 |         1 |
> +------+-------+--------+-----------+
> ```

The `MAXNUM_OP` column shows the results you wanted, but you never explained why some of the values were supposed to be null.  The `MAXNUM` column shows the results that I think you described in the text of your post.

Comment: I believe if you use `decode` you can avoid writing the `first` aggregate function twice in the `select` list. Other than that, this is almost surely the best answer.

Comment: it's not working properly when the table contains rows with num = 0, right? (e.g. | z | 1.8 | 0 |)

Comment: @Naminee It should work.  I may have just mistyped my test data and left that row out.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `first_value` and `row_number` analytical function as following:

```
Select cola,
       date, 
       case when row_number() over (partition by cola order by date) > 1 then
             first_value(num) over (partition by cola order by date) 
       end as maxnum
From your_table;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: it's not working properly when the table contains rows with num = 0, right? (e.g. | z | 1.8 | 0 |)

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use a subquery.

```
SELECT t1.cola,
       t1.date,
       (SELECT max(t2.num)
               FROM elbat t2
               WHERE t2.cola = t1.cola
                     AND t2.date < t1.date) maxnum
       FROM elbat t1;
```

Comment: since it's a huge database a subquery like this won't suitible because of the performance